# Scale a matrix to predefined stddev and mean

Tags: r, python, standardization, arithmetic, scipy

Today i stumbled upon an filtering algorithm which as final step it says that it

> scale the output matrix so it will have the same stddev and
>   mean as the input matrix.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. The question is a bit ambiguous however because there could be, depending on the context, various definition of what is meant by 'sttdev' and 'mean' of a matrix. 
Here I consider these operators in their simplest (element-wise) sense.

Here is your input matrix:

```
n<-100
p<-5
X<-matrix(rnorm(n*p),nc=p)
```

Here is your algorithm:

```
Myalgo<-function(X){
X*matrix(rnorm(nrow(X)*ncol(X)),nc=ncol(X))+matrix(rnorm(nrow(X)*ncol(X)),nc=ncol(X)) 
}

Z<-Myalgo(X)
```

Now, `Z` doesn't have the same `mean` `stdev` as `X`

```
mean(Z)
mean(X)

sd(Z) 
sd(X)
```

But you can always rescale `Z` so that it does:

```
Z<-Z/sd(Z)*sd(X)
Z<-Z-mean(Z)+mean(X)
sd(Z)
mean(Z)
```

Comment: Does this relate/replicate part of, or completely, the process of linearly stretching an (digital) image to another image's Mean and StdDev?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: One more time (for clarity!): ...linearly stretching an (digital) image so as to match another image's Mean and StdDev. Thanks for the heads-up @user603.

Comment: I don't know what the expression "standard deviation of an image" means

Comment: Say you have a simple 8-bit digital image. Consider all of its pixel values building a vector. This vector (well, the image) has a unique Histogram, a Mean and a Standard Deviation.

Comment: Well, you can also see an image as a matrix... Rows * Columns! :-)

Comment: As I mentioned in the preambule of my answer, there are various definition of what the 'Sdev' of a matrix means. I don't know which one of these definitions is the generally accepted one in the context of image processing.